# Can't set Live Photo as wallpaper, only Still and Perspective options

Tags: iphone, ios, wallpaper

When I want to set a Live Photo as my wallpaper it only had Still and Perspective as options. In Settings → Wallpaper it only has Still and Dynamic. Can I do anything?

[image]

Comment: We're here to help you with your Apple or iOS issues - your frustration is all your own. You need to give us some basic details - iPhone model, iOS, have you tested using Apple's own Live Wallpapers, to eliminate error in the file you're trying to use...

Answer (score 1):

As Settings → Wallpaper doesn't have a Live Photo section, it would appear your device is not compatible with Live Photos. Live Photos are available on iPhone 6s and later.